# What is the difference between markup, coding, scripting, shell scripting, and programming languages?

Tags: shell, scripting, difference

- *What is the difference between coding, scripting, shell scripting, and programming languages?*
- *What is front end, back end and middle ware?*
- *Can you not use the same language for front end and back end and middle ware?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **script** language usually doesn't deal with low level things, and are most of the times interpreted (such as Javascript). They should be easy to learn and write.

A **programming language** is much wider : it gives instructions to a machine.

**Front-end** is what the user sees : GUI, website design... For web design, languages like HTML and CSS are used to code the content of the page, along with script languages such as JS.

**Back-end** is the internal process of the program/page.

Languages are usually specialized to be more effective for front or back-end using certain methods :

- **Native instructions and syntax :** CSS is designed to go along HTML, and provides direct integration with HTML tags.
- **Low or high level :** Back-end languages may need to be more low level, to manage fine networking for example.

We can use the same langage for front-end and back-end, but it will be less effective, and we may just use two effective languages rather than using one language but less effective.

Notice that low-end and back-end *usually* don't interact directly at the language level (classes, etc.)